# Mirroring object on Z axis not correct

Tags: mirror, axis, mirror-modifier

I am making a thor's hammer design following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yxrke72isQ .
at about 1:17:20, they mirror the rune like curves on the z axis. when i try this, it mirrors correctly on
X, but when i mirror it on Z, it is a little offset,and is not touching the hammer:

[image: offset on the Z axis]

what am i doing wrong? this tutorial is pretty old so if there's something in lender please tell how to solve this.

The .Blend file:
[image]

EDIT
when i set the origin to geometry in the cube, this happens:

[image]

Comment: the mirror will use the origin as center, so you can either move the origin a bit or lower down the mesh a bit in Edit mode then lift the object up a bit in Object mode

Comment: @moonboots but when i grab the curves the original curve goes through the cube

Comment: it's hard to understand, have you converted your curve to mesh? Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes i have converted the object

Comment: i have edited the question with .Blend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're doing here is using your hammer object (called *Cube*) as *Mirror Object*. The problem is that the origin of *Cube* is not place at the center of its geometry, so the mirrored mesh will be a bit shifted. To fix that, in *Edit* mode select the top and bottom vertices of Cube and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then back into *Object* mode, right click > *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*. Now the ornment will stick to the surface.

[image]

Comment: when i set the origin to geometry, the cube seems to collapse into itself

Comment: check the edit in the question

Comment: yes sorry I meant  right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.

Comment: that worked thanks:)